# tengo un problema actulizando el campo de otra tabla con un trigger

Tags: mysql

lo que sucede es que estoy tratando de guardar la suma de varios articulos
en otra tabla y al insertar los datos el guarda pero en la otra tabla 
deja el total de la suma en 0.
este es mi codigo:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `codigo_barras_update` AFTER INSERT ON `vta_ped_lin_g`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE vta_ped_g SET vta_ped_g.TOT_PED = vta_ped_g.TOT_PED + NEW.IMP WHERE vta_ped_g.ID = NEW.ID;
END
```

Comment: Muestra la estructura de ambas tablas, la puedes obtener con un `SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla;` y muestra un ejemplo concreto de consulta se inserción en el que ocurre lo que dices en la pregunta. Al TRIGGER en sí no le veo ningún problema, entonces el problema está en otra parte o en que no estás usando los elementos correctos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!